# How to seperate Data from a row and count each Data using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Can any one help me out here with a syntax to split the data in a row and see if the splitted data is appearing again the count of that splitted info should be obtained.

If you see the below input table. C1 has a data like ABC, ACD, BCE etc.. I want to split that and have a count for each specific data and also the total count.

Help is appreciated in MYSQL

Query i tried in SQL server: As a new bibe i to MYSQL i was able to get data as whole but i was unable to split. For Example, i know `select C1 from inputtable`. But i unable to get idea to split the data that a row have in a specified column.

Diagramatical Explanation:

```
Input Table:

C1        
----------
ABC 
ACD
BCE
NULL
A

Output Table:

Column1            Count            TotalCount
------------------------------------------------------
A                  3                  4
B                  2                  4
C                  3                  4
D                  1                  4
E                  1                  4
```

Comment: What type is the data? Are you splitting with a delimiter or fixed width?

Comment: @DaleM I have a 10 Byte data. ABCDEFGHIJ of which any combination can be possible like A, ABC, AD, ABCDEF..etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting data into an arbitrary number of columns would require stored procedures or some similar uglyness. Splitting into ten columns is possible, but turning these columns into rows so you can aggregate them would again require ugly code. All of this indicates that your schema probably is in violation with the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form): you're storing multiple values in a single table “cell”. Can you modify the schema, or do you have to use that one?

If you have to use that one, here is some ugly code to get you startet. It produces the requested output on your sample input, as [tested on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6146/1).

```
SELECT q1.chr, COUNT(*), q2.cnt
FROM ( SELECT SUBSTR(C1, 1, 1) AS chr FROM tab
       UNION ALL
       SELECT SUBSTR(C1, 2, 1) AS chr FROM tab
       UNION ALL
       SELECT SUBSTR(C1, 3, 1) AS chr FROM tab
     ) AS q1,
     ( SELECT COUNT(C1) AS cnt FROM tab ) AS q2
WHERE q1.chr != ''
GROUP BY q1.chr
```

Note that I definitely would not advise you to write things this way. Use a proper database schema instead, where you don't have to repeat lines a fixed number of times. And also consider using a separate query to fetch the total, as repeating that for every row of the result appears rather pointless.

Comment: does MySQL support recursion like SQL Server - this would greatly simplify the problem.

Comment: @DaleM I have to use this ugly Schema :(. However, i am iterating it with java to do this in dynamic. Thanks Dale you have helped me from this hectic problem. I wish MYSQL have more advanced features like SQL SERVER.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a fixed set ABCDEFGHIJ, then something like this might be workable:

```
SELECT a.l         AS `Column1`
     , SUM(1)      AS `Count`
     , c.cnt       AS `TotalCount`
  FROM (
         SELECT CONVERT('A' USING latin1) AS l UNION ALL SELECT 'B'  
          UNION ALL SELECT 'C' UNION ALL SELECT 'D'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'E' UNION ALL SELECT 'F'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'G' UNION ALL SELECT 'H'
          UNION ALL SELECT 'I' UNION ALL SELECT 'J'
       ) a
  JOIN input_table t
    ON INSTR(t.c1,a.l)
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT COUNT(1) AS cnt FROM input_table) c
 GROUP BY a.l
 ORDER BY a.l
```

NOTE: the CONVERT is only necessary if the client characterset doesn't match the column c1 characterset... it's there to avoid Error 1267 Illegal mix of collations.

If you want to omit rows where the count is 0 (like the selected answer does), then you could add a

```
HAVING SUM(1) > 1
```

predicate.

Comment: This is worth understanding how we can write logic in MYSQL.